# what update is required for my tensorflow-lite-library in androidstudio?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I have created  a tensorflowlite model with vgg19.h5 , what update is required for my tensorflow-lite-library, my default gradle script version 0.1.0

want to create a android app using my vgg19 model for image classification.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.